# Powering a STM32 Nucleo board using batteries/power bank

Tags: power, batteries, stm32, nucleo

I was wondering if it's possible to power a STM32 Nucleo L073RZ using a power bank via USB or a battery.

I tried using the power bank to power the board however, LD1 would constantly flash red. I even tried using a wall socket to power the device however the same issue would occur.

There was a answer which has the same issue but the answer which was to put a jumper on JP1 didn't work for me. It would still constantly blinks red at LD1.
[Possible to power STM32 Nucleo boards with USB battery pack?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179579/possible-to-power-stm32-nucleo-boards-with-usb-battery-pack)

Is there any other ways to power via power bank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NUCLEO board needs](http://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823.pdf) enumeration from USB host if it is powered from USB connector.

USB power banks nor wall adapters can't provide USB enumeration, they are not intelligent.

To power the board without USB enumeration, you need to make a special cable, and connect 5V to E5V pins on JP5 (see Table 8), and the other (GND) to ground pin of the NUCLEO.

Also keep in mind that if your NUCLEO would occasionally go to sleep state and the consumption drops below 50 - 70 mA, many powerbanks would drop the supply (to save their internal power), so your system will shut down catastrophically. To see your options, search for "powerbank" in SE, [like this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/270337/117785).